# How Can i use Azure Search Like Syntax

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In my Azure Search ,  i have two document , one column is call "Description"

And two record like this

```
[ 
{"Description": "XARATM | KONE"},
{"Description": "ATM | RCOR"}
]
```

my problem is ,
when i use Azure Search to search my record 
like:

```
https://myservice.search.windows.net/indexes/searchproduct/docs?search=ATM&api-version=2014-07-31-Preview
```

they just return one record {"Description": "ATM | RCOR"} , but i need two record. 
so can i use some syntax like T-SQL

```
SELECT * FROM SearchProduct WHERE Description Like '%ATM%'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Search does support wildcards, but only in the format ATM*, that would allow to search for words in the form of suffixes such as ATMa or ATMb.  In your case, you would need *ATM, which is not currently supported with Azure Search.

To learn more about wildcards for suffix, please visit the MSDN API documentation on this topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798920.aspx).

Liam

Comment: Thank you , i really want report this issue for M$ ... , it's look like anyone will need it

Comment: A good place for you and others to let us know about this is our UserVoice page.  Here is a direct link to this particular feature request where you can also add specific comments if you like: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search?query=wildcard

Comment: Also, I would like to add that even though Lucene (and layers built on top of it), support wildcards like this as a query operator, these are brute-forced against the inverted index unless you have a custom indexing/querying scheme. As a result, if indexes grow to any non-trivial size performance will suffer significantly.  As a result, even though we do understand the value of this feature, we want to make sure that if this is implemented, that we take these performance factors into account.

Comment: In fact . i abandon Azure Search . And hug ElasticSearch .  
i'm ask this question in MSDN  . if you want choose Azure Search . maybe you need look before use . 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e02ac3b3-72cc-4433-833d-29c834463244/azure-search-preview-can-i-use-prefix-operator-?forum=azuresearch

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't use prefix wildcards in Azure search, you can use regular expressions which may be able to handle allowing some variance in your search criteria.

https://littlekendra.com/2016/10/25/wildcard-vs-regular-expressions-lucene-query-in-azure-search/

Examples:

business_title:/(Sen|Jun)ior/

business_title:/(.*)rchit(.*)/