# How to use sql like clause in azure search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using azure search and i want to use like clause of sql

Query i am using in azure is

```
https://Serivename.search.windows.net/indexes/catalogsearch/docs?
api-version=2015-02-28&search =Mc*&queryType=simple&searchMode=all
```

but it is not working

What I have tried:

[How Can i use Azure Search Like Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001981/how-can-i-use-azure-search-like-syntax)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/lucene-query-language-in-azure-search

Comment: While editing your question, I noticed you have a space between `search` and `=Mc*`, so it reads as `&search =Mc*&...` That would be an issue.

Comment: I tried what you suggest. but not working. 
i tried another option 
$filter=Name eq 'mcdonal'&queryType=simple&searchMode=all. is working properly 
But
$filter=Name eq 'mc*'&queryType=simple&searchMode=all.  is also not working

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers in the comments about using the wildcard * to do Like% style queries, however sometimes you might want to do %Like queries as well.  For this, you would need to create a [custom analyzer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/).

The reason why you need to do this is because the way default indexing works is that it indexes the starts of a word.  For example, for the word Microsoft, the indexing would be done over M, then Mi, then Mic, etc...

This makes it easy to do a search for Mic%, but it does not work for %soft.  So to get this to work , we need to use a bit of a trick where we tell the analyzer to reverse the words and then index index those (you can see the example of this for the analyzer "suffixAnalyzer" below).  For the example Microsoft, it would do indexing of t, tf, tfo, tfos, etc...  Certainly this would not work as it is since we want to be able to search for %soft, but the indexing reversed the words (i.e. tofs rather than soft).  So all we do is to have an analyzer that reveres it (you can see the example of this for the analyzer "revereseText" below).

Now all we need is a new field that uses the "suffixAnalyzer" for the indexing and the "revereseText" for the searchAnalyzer (you can see the example of this for the field "suffixName" below).

```
"fields": [
    { "name":"suffixName", "type":"Edm.String", "searchable":true, "searchAnalyzer":"reverseText", "indexAnalyzer":"suffixAnalyzer" }
]

"analyzers": [
    {"name":"suffixAnalyzer","@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer","tokenizer":"standard","tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "reverse", "my_edgeNGram" ]},
    {"name":"reverseText","@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer","tokenizer":"standard","tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "reverse" ]}
]
```

Once you have all this, you can do a search over the suffixName field for "soft" and it will find it at a really fast query rate.

By the way, you can actually create a prefix analyzer with the following analyzer which make it so that you don't actually have to use the wildcard.

```
"analyzers": [
    {"name":"prefixAnalyzer","@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer","tokenizer":"standard","tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "my_edgeNGram" ]}
]

"fields": [
    { "name":"partialName", "type":"Edm.String", "searchable":true, "searchAnalyzer":"standard", "indexAnalyzer":"prefixAnalyzer" },
]
```